# PHP range() function in .NET?

Tags: .net, php, range

I need to generate a list of sequential numbers.  I know Ruby you can do 1..10 or PHP you can do range(1, 10).  Anything like that in .Net already, or do I have to write it?   Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C# (with .NET 3.0 or higher) this should do the job:

```
IEnumerable<int> myRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
public List<int> Range(int start, int finish)
{
  List<int> retList = new List<int>();
  for(int i = start; i <= finish; i++)
  {
     retList.Add(i);
  }
  return retList;
}
```

Comment: I actually wrote a method exactly like this before I saw you could use Enumerable.Range.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's new to me also. I really need to get a 3.0 book, but I think I'm just going to wait until 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)()